# How can I get a reference to an EditText in a ListView?

Tags: android

I'm creating a form that uses a ListView. Each row in my ListView is defined by form_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textFormItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:ellipsize="end" android:singleLine="true" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/editFormItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm planning to stick this layout into a custom Adapter that subclasses `SimpleAdapter`. But I'm wondering how will I be able to access each EditText and get a reference to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editFormItem);
```

Comment: Since this is going to be a ListView with several entries that contain EditTexts, will this work for each of the many EditTexts?

Comment: Yes. Important is that the "view" part is exactly one of the items (then it will only look inside that item). For example if you want to handle it in onItemClick(), you will get View v as parameter - and this will be the single item that you just clicked and running findViewById on it will find you exactly the editText of the item you just clicked.

Comment: Ah, I didn't catch the `view` part of it. I'll give this a shot.

Comment: You can also see as an example another related question I answered today (which was up-voted and accepted) with example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479524/onitemclick-two-listviews-problem/6479594#comment-7617016